# Getting a specific subset of a string

Tags: php

I'm getting responses such as:

> Si. USC01019181 j2log-aGoWZbUSKJWNYALQQEXG-detail This is my response.
>   Si. RVC000827503 Si.

How would it be possible to get the "Si." part of the response and ignore the rest/duplicates, bearing in mind that the response sentence can be something other than "Si.". My regex is pretty poor, so I'm not sure how to even start with this one. Note that the response above is posted as-received, complete with newlines (there are none) etc.

Comment: If the text that you want to grep is always on the first line of the responce, then you only have to read the first line and dump the rest.. You can do it like: `substr($str, 0, strpos($str, "\n"))`

Comment: Which of the `What duh heck!` do you want ?? or do you want `What duh heck!` because it occurs more than once

Comment: Doesn't seem like there are any newlines :/ Goddamn it.

Comment: @Baba Any string that occurs more than once might work but as I said my regex is pretty bad and there are no newlines

Comment: @WtotheX what happens if there are no duplicated .. what would be selected .. don't worry about your regex i'll work something out

Comment: @Baba Hey man, I updated the question. Looks like there are no newlines at all. Basically I'm trying to parse responses from Cleverbot

Comment: @Baba Maybe some sort of regex that can parses anything before the USC string?

Comment: @Wtothex there are new lines ..... if its just the "Si." part you want that should not be difficult .. it only occur in the port part of each message

Comment: @Baba The response I'm wanting will always be at the start, before the USCetc string. It can be a few words long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
$text = array();
$text[] = 'Si. USC01019181 j2log-aGoWZbUSKJWNYALQQEXG-detail This is my response. ';
$text[] = "Cotton eye joe. USC01019181 j2log-vBaIUwYSOJRZTAPCQISG-detail";

foreach ( $text as $msg ) {
    echo strstr($msg, '.', true) , "\n";
}
```

Output

```
Si
Cotton eye joe
```

Comment: I tried it out but it'll only get the first word. For example, I got this as a response "Cotton eye joe. USC01019181 j2log-vBaIUwYSOJRZTAPCQISG-detail" and strstr only managed to get "Cotton"

Comment: Ok i think i know what you want now .. hold on

Comment: I would like to get "Cotton eye joe." without anything else if it is possible.